# get response from git when push is completed

Tags: node.js, git, electron

I have been looking for a solution when a relatively large(10-20mb) file is drag and dropped to the folder which needs to be pushed to its git branch from an electron app just after the custom quit button of the app is clicked.

Currently, I am not using any node module for git actions. I am doing it via exec(git commands) but it seems I need to wait for a response in order to inform the user that the files are pushed and it is okay to close the app.

My question is, are there any methods, best practices where a response is returned when a large file is push is successful

Thanks

Comment: So what is the question? Git is done pushing when the git process terminates without an error message (and with an exit code of 0).

Comment: exec(git bla bla) command is not waiting for a response from the server. My question is, are there any method, best practice where a response is returned when a large file is push is successful

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to respond to that. **Again:** Git is done pushing when the git process terminates without an error message (and with an exit code of 0). If you don't wait for git to terminate, then git is not yet done. **Seriously**, what is the question here?

Comment: To more clearly answer your question: Yes, best practices are to wait for the git process to terminate and then inspect the exit code. If it is 0 then whatever you asked git to do was successful. Otherwise, it wasn't.

Comment: Actually, exec(git bla bla) returns instantly. exec does not return status of the push itself but checks if the command is reasonable or not. lets say I gave the command as "gi push " instead of "git push" it reruns an error but the command's response is not evaluated. So basically, I need a lib or usage will do .then() and .catch()

Comment: Deploy a post-receive or post-update hook in the remote repo. https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Comment: I found my error or misusage. I was calling an alias, I named it as commitx, on .gitconfig file at PATH: %userprofile%

commitx = "!git add . && git commit -a -m sync && git push --set-upstream origin " + branchName

When I called git commands one by one git server returns the responses that I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS is asynchronous so you need to add a callback to your call:

```
exec('git push', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log('Done');
})
```

See [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) for `exec`.